# Purpose of rotation of a Function or Graph

Tags: functions, trigonometry, rotations, applications

You are able to rotate any function by an arbitrary angle around the origin using the formula,
$$y\cos\theta-x\sin\theta=f(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta)$$You can also do similar rotations for polar graphs, or multivariable functions; however, what would the actual purpose of doing so be? Possibly making a certain problem easier to evaluate or does it have some application in real life?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's used in almost **every** field of physics and engineering. You write a matrix associated with the rotation and you apply it to your vector.

Comment: What would be a specific example of this? I tried searching myself but I couldn't find anything regarding my question.

Comment: For example, I work in a computational fluid dynamics software. I need to make the plane's wing have different angle (angle of attack) to find the best angle (stall angle). Unfortunately you can't move the wing in that software, so what I do is that I rotate the wind and my wing stays horizontal. Then I applied a rotation of parameter the angle theta to my vector of wind. Then I start like 1000 computations for angles between 0° and 30° and then I get a nice graph.